# Development of Visual Studio IDE

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

What does the Visual Studio development team at Microsoft use to develop new versions of Visual Studio? Do they use VS2005 to develop VS2008? Thinking about it makes my head hurt a little...

Comment: They're using VS 2012 to develop VS 2010 right now.

Comment: I recently heard they use Eclipse.

Comment: They are using emacs and C. A fact.

Comment: please change the question to "Development Of Visual Studio"...

Comment: @Scott: are you per chance confusing this with the story of MS _acquiring_ the company that developed TFS integration for Eclipse?

Comment: LOL, nice question (in a good way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We [dogfood](http://news.zdnet.com/2100-3513_22-130518.html) our products, and VS is no exception.

/me goes back to his happy world of rainbows, unicorns, lambdas, `auto`, and `dynamic` ;)

Comment: Ha! Well, you would know! Thanks for the answer...it's something i have always pondered.

Answer (score 16):

One of the PDC videos I recently watched said they use VS2010 to develop VS2010.

You may imagine how quickly bugs get fixed that way.

Comment: I would expect most IDE developers use their own IDEs to develop (with the possible exception of dynamic language IDEs).

Comment: +1 for that. It would actually be a good idea to force developers to use their own software a bit...

Comment: Sounds like the opposite of the snake eating its own tail... the ultimate in dogfooding!

Comment: Doesn't the same phenomenon occur in other developer oriented products? VCS software usually ends up managing its own source after it reaches a stable point.

Answer (score 2):

They start on an abacus and work there way through mathematical instruments until they reach computers. At this point they stop and roll another funny cigarette and wonder is this what life has come to?

Answer (score 0):

C was implemented to write UNIX.  UNIX is written in C.  On UNIX, currently.  At some point, you use what you've built to keep building it.

I'd imagine the very first go of VS2008 is written in VS2005, but then they start using VS2008 as soon as is feasible to continue developing VS2008.

Comment: "I'd imagine the very first go of VS2008 is written in VS2005" - one important thing to understand here is that "vs2005" and "vs2008" are discrete points for external customers. From the inside, it's more like a single continuum: VS2008 starts its life as a branch of VS2005 code, and so on.